# Gray codes addition

Tags: c++, c, gray-code

Is there any known way to compute the addition (and maybe the subtraction) of two Gray codes without having to convert the two Gray codes to regular binary, perform a binary addition then convert the result back to a Gray code? I managed to write increment and decrement functions, but the addition and subtraction seem even less documented and harder to write.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to keep a regular representation in memory, manipulate that, and then converted to gray code whenever needed?

Comment: First define the behaviour of what must happen when result would be negative or would overflow (as Gray code are normally used as fixed-bit-width values).

Comment: @meaning-matters Well, I only work with unsigned gray codes, therefore, I don't care about signed values. Ideally speaking, I would like to have the gray code overflow the same way than the underlying integer, but I highly doubt it is easy to achieve.

Comment: @Marcos But I have to admit that the question is more driven by mere curiosity than by any real-world application.

Comment: How wide?  Limited to unsigned numbers?

Comment: @chux I am using templates which accept anything that is ok with `std::is_unsigned<>`. Until there, all my operations do not depend on the size of the unisgned integer.

Comment: You may get better responses on [math](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) or [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com).  I look forward to the answer.

Comment: Given how [easy it is](http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/tricks/gray-code-conversion) to convert to greycode from binary I'm pretty sure converting both values to binary, adding or subtracting, and converting back to greycode will be faster that iterating across the bits, unless you are doing this in an FPGA or something similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [this document](http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~storer/JimPuzzles/MANIP/ChineseRings/READING/GrayCodesDoran.pdf) under #6, there is an algorithm for serial Gray code addition (copied directly; note, that `⊕` is `xor`):

```pascal
procedure add (n: integer; A,B:word; PA,PB:bit;
               var S:word; var PS:bit; var CE, CF:bit);
var i: integer; E, F, T: bit;
begin
   E := PA; F := PB;
   for i:= 0 to n-1 do begin {in parallel, using previous inputs}
       S[i] := (E and F) ⊕ A[i] ⊕ B[i];
       E := (E and (not F)) ⊕ A[i];
       F := ((not E) and F) ⊕ B[i];
   end;
   CE := E; CF := F;
end;
```

> This adds the Gray code words A and B to form the Gray code word S. The operand parities are PA and PB, the sum parity is PS. This propagates two carry bits internally, E and F, and produces two external carry bits CE and CF

Unfortunately, it doesn't state anything about subtraction, but I assume, when you can encode negative numbers, you can use addition for that.

Comment: Haha, it was the only document I found that talked about addition, but I couldn't find what Å meant, thanks for the explanation :) Still I have problems understanding it. Hope I will finally get it...

Comment: @Morwenn I'm taking an educated guess about what symbol that is intended to be. I suspect that this is intended to be instructional, not practical, except to demonstrate the algorithm for hardware implementation.

Answer (score 6):

I accepted @Sebastian Dressler's answer because the suggested algorithm indeed works. For the sake of completeness, I propose here a corresponding C99 implementation of the algorithm (C++ compatible):

```
// lhs and rhs are encoded as Gray codes
unsigned add_gray(unsigned lhs, unsigned rhs)
{
    // e and f, initialized with the parity of lhs and rhs
    // (0 means even, 1 means odd)
    bool e = __builtin_parity(lhs);
    bool f = __builtin_parity(rhs);

    unsigned res = 0u;
    for (unsigned i = 0u ; i < CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned) ; ++i)
    {
        // Get the ith bit of rhs and  lhs
        bool lhs_i = (lhs >> i) & 1u;
        bool rhs_i = (rhs >> i) & 1u;

        // Copy e and f (see {in parallel} in the original paper)
        bool e_cpy = e;
        bool f_cpy = f;

        // Set the ith bit of res
        unsigned res_i = (e_cpy & f_cpy) ^ lhs_i ^ rhs_i;
        res |= (res_i << i);

        // Update e and f
        e = (e_cpy & (!f_cpy)) ^ lhs_i;
        f = ((!e_cpy) & f_cpy) ^ rhs_i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Note: `__builtin_parity` is a compiler intrinsic (GCC and Clang) that returns the parity of the number of set bits in an integer (if the intrinsic does not exist, there are [other methods](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/69122) to compute it by hand). A gray code is even when it has an even number of set bits. The algorithm can still be improved, but this implementation is rather faithful to the original algorithm. If you want details about an optimized implementation, you can have a look at [this Q&A](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/69122) on Code Review.

Answer (score 3):

I recently devised a new algorithm to add two Gray codes. Unfortunately, it is still slower than the naive double-conversion solution and is also slower than Harold Lucal's algorithm (the one in the accepted answer). But any new solution to a problem is welcome, right?

```
// lhs and rhs are encoded as Gray codes
unsigned add_gray(unsigned lhs, unsigned rhs)
{
    // Highest power of 2 in lhs and rhs
    unsigned lhs_base = hyperfloor(lhs);
    unsigned rhs_base = hyperfloor(rhs);

    if (lhs_base == rhs_base) {
        // If lhs and rhs are equal, return lhs * 2
        if (lhs == rhs) {
            return (lhs << 1u) ^ __builtin_parity(lhs);
        }
        // Else return base*2 + (lhs - base) + (rhs - base)
        return (lhs_base << 1u) ^ add_gray(lhs_base ^ lhs, lhs_base ^ rhs);
    }

    // It's easier to operate from the greatest value
    if (lhs_base < rhs_base) {
        swap(&lhs, &rhs);
        swap(&lhs_base, &rhs_base);
    }

    // Compute lhs + rhs
    if (lhs == lhs_base) {
        return lhs ^ rhs;
    }

    // Compute (lhs - base) + rhs
    unsigned tmp = add_gray(lhs ^ lhs_base, rhs);
    if (hyperfloor(tmp) < lhs_base) {
        // Compute base + (lhs - base) + rhs
        return lhs_base ^ tmp;
    }
    // Here, hyperfloor(lhs) == hyperfloor(tmp)
    // Compute hyperfloor(lhs) * 2 + ((lhs - hyperfloor(lhs)) + rhs) - hyperfloor(lhs)
    return (lhs_base << 1u) ^ (lhs_base ^ tmp);
}
```

The algorithm uses the following utility functions in order tow work correctly:

```
// Swap two values
void swap(unsigned* a, unsigned* b)
{
    unsigned temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

// Isolate the most significant bit
unsigned isomsb(unsigned x)
{
    for (unsigned i = 1u ; i <= CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned) / 2u ; i <<= 1u) {
        x |= x >> i;
    }
    return x & ~(x >> 1u);
}

// Return the greatest power of 2 not higher than
// x where x and the power of 2 are encoded in Gray
// code
unsigned hyperfloor(unsigned x)
{
    unsigned msb = isomsb(x);
    return msb | (msb >> 1u);
}
```

---

## So, how does it work?

I have to admit, it's quite a wall of code for something as « simple » as an addition. It is mostly based on observations about bit patterns in Gray codes; that is, I didn't prove anything formally, but I have yet to find cases where the algorithm doesn't work (if I don't take into account overflow, it does not handle overflow). Here are the main observations used to construct the algorithm, assume that everything is a Gray code:

- 2 * n = (n << 1) ⊕ parity(n)
- If a is a power of 2 and a > b, then a ⊕ b = a + b
- Consequently, i a is a power of 2 and a < b, then a ⊕ b = a - b. This will only work if b < 2 * a though.
- If a and b have the same hyperfloor but are not equal, then a + b = (hyperfloor(a) << 1) ⊕ ((hyperfloor(a) ⊕ a) + (hyperfloor(b) ⊕ b)).

Basically, it means that we know how to multiply by 2, how to add a power of 2 to a smaller Gray code and how to subtract a power of 2 from a Gray code that is bigger than that power of 2 but smaller than the next power of 2. Everything else are tricks so that we can reason in terms of equal values or powers of 2.

If you want more details/information, you can also check [this Q&A](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/86376/15094) on Code Review which proposes a modern C++ implementation of the algorithm as well as some optimizations (as a bonus, there are some nice MathJax equations that we can't have here :D).